# Linux and JBoss: Clustering software recomendation

Tags: 2013-sp1, java, linux

We have to build a new architecture and we calculated that we will need four presentation servers.
We are using Java to develop our website and we will deploy it to Jboss under a linux platform.

We don't want to publish to four local file systems, one for each server. Then, we think to use a clustering software to publish in one place and connect every server with this file system.

Someone has experience using a clustering software in a similar architecture? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of architecture is perfectly possible, with files stored on some kind of shared resource across the web servers. Usually I see a NAS or SAN type device used for this purpose. Steer clear of syncing technologies - in my experience they are prone to issues.

However, these architectures are less common in Tridion deployments today. I would urge to you consider a more modern approach, where all content is stored in the content delivery database and accessed via the Content Service by an MVC style web application, such as SDL's own DXA.